# Is there a way to pass an argument to a view without using the url?

Tags: blocks, views

UPDATE: Shawn's answer is correct but I'd like to mention for anyone else looking to implement it. The arguments must match the contextual filters you've added, in the same order.

---

Right now I'm embedding views using

```
print views_embed_view('customview', 'customblock');
```

in a block. Is there a way that I can still embed a view in a block and pass in a parameter to it. I'd like to create a filter like this

```
print views_embed_view('customview', 'customblock', 'customcategory');
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your example does exactly what you're wanting. Read the docs on [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7)...

> "...: Any additional parameters will be passed as arguments."

Comment: I'm wanting to filter by category and have made category the first contextual filter but when I enter print views_embed_view('customview', 'customblock', 'customcategory'); I get no results. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Nevermind turns out I was supposed to use the term id rather than the name.